# Kickstart developing Twitter application

Tags: twitter

Any good source/website/inputs/sample to kickstart developing a twitter application using twitter API?

Edit : I don't know what languages can be used to develop it. But I am familiar with VB .NET and Java.

Comment: It depends on your language selection. For example, for Ruby I was using the sources http://twitter.rubyforge.org/.

Comment: @all : Thanks. I start to get the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in C# or VB.NET I can heartily recommend [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.com/).

Edit: [Here are some snippets using TweetSharp](http://snipt.org/box/Dimebrain/), in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! 
I gave it a read. It's a wrapper for twitter API? Do you have any sample to develop it using 'native' twitter API?

Comment: No, sorry - but if you're going to be developing in VB.NET, I can't really see why you would want to use the REST API over TweetSharp; you'd basically just be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I just wanna know how it is done. Curiosity, I would say. There is no doubt I probably cannot write a better wrapper than TweetSharp, but that's not going to stop me from exploring the ways. Thanks for the advice. I think what I am going to now to find a open source wrapper and see how they wrap the API.

Comment: Fair enough, I can understand that! You can get the source for TweetSharp from http://code.google.com/p/tweetsharp/source/checkout

Comment: The snippet doesn't work. See question @ my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824723/simple-problem-with-tweetsharp I copied hello, world, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Start here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation) and then explore the links.

Comment: I was there yesterday. My thought would be using HTTP to interact with twitter server. But I want to see if my thought is the 'correct' implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Twitter library in VB.NET.  It's free and open source and may be helpful to you.  http://twittervb.codeplex.com/