# (Simple) problem with TweetSharp

Tags: .net, tweetsharp

Here is what I did :
  1. I create a C# project from VS .NET 2005 (Console application)
  2. Attached the library from tweetsharp.com
  3. I copied and pasted and tried to run

The  code

```
//setting up a request is unchanged
var twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest()
.AuthenticateAs(user, password)
.Statuses().OnHomeTimeline().AsXml();

// In past releases 'response' used to be a string, now it's a TwitterResult object
var response = twitter.Request();
```

I can't get it running. The error is :

```
'Dimebrain.TweetSharp.Fluent.IFluentTwitter' does not contain a definition for    'AuthenticateAs'... Data\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only 'using' directive you need for that code snippet should be:

```
using Dimebrain.TweetSharp.Fluent
```

You'll probably also eventually need:

```
using Dimebrain.TweetSharp.Extensions;
using Dimebrain.TweetSharp.Model;
```

...so you might as well add those too.

We do plan to collapse a lot of TweetSharp into a single namespace at some point, but for now that should get you most of what you need.

Comment: Object twitter = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest().AuthenticateAs("aa", "bb")
.Statuses().OnHomeTimeline().AsXml();

The above is my code. Still gives me the same error message. Probably I am using 2005?

Comment: Ahh, yes. You'll need to move to .Net framework 3.5 and VS 2008 to get it working since most of the methods are Extension methods and won't work otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! I will get an express edition and read about the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are referencing the right namespaces in your code - I think in this case Dimebrain.TweetSharp.Extensions.

There's [a more thorough snippet here on the TweetSharp site](http://tweetsharp.com/page/5/).

Comment: Not working. But I will keep trying though. Still the same error message.